# Copy of a database with an existing database with schema and data in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have two databases one is having master kind of tables and other will have transaction data.
I should create a new database with a structure of an existing database to my clients. Here is the scenario..

If the particular db will comes under transaction type then structure of an existing db should copy
If the particular db will comes under master type then structure of an existing db along with data should copy

i.e Transaction--> Only Schema
       Master--> Schema+Data

I tried with Generate script, Is there any way to automate this process instead of manually generating script for both schema and Schema+Data for every copy of a new db.

Please suggest.

Comment: You might consider doing a backup/restore for your "Master" database.  That way you get Schema+Data without scripting at all.

Answer (score 1):

Create two template databases - once - one with the schema, and one with schema + data - populated with the manual generate scripts method.

Take a backup of each.

When you want to create a new database, instead of a manual `CREATE DATABASE` and then manual population, restore the backups as new names and the `WITH MOVE` options to move the data/log files.

Refresh the templates, obviously, every time you make meaningful changes to the schema and/or data that you want used for future, new databases.

You could reduce this work by putting just the schema in `model`, then `CREATE DATABASE` would create an empty database with your schema, and you'd only need to do something for the one with the data. Or vice-versa. But note that this will affect *all* future databases.